# Set up a local server on an external hard drive - Forbidden error

Tags: php, macos, localhost, apache2, osx-elcapitan

I have a Mac OSX El Capitan operating system. Since my laptop has limited space, I am trying to set up a local server on my 1TB external hard drive with the url http://media.database/, and that uses PHP. I have set it up the best I know how, but when I go to the page, it says "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server."

I have set apache and host files as best I know how, but I'm still pretty new to this sort of thing. I have listed my updates to those files below and restarted the apache server using `sudo apachectl restart`, which has gotten me this far. Can someone enlighten me on what I might be missing. All help is greatly appreciated.

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName media.database
    DocumentRoot "file:///Volumes/DBTARA/media/"
    <Directory "file:///Volumes/DBTARA/media/">
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 media.database
```

/etc/apache2/users/vmbmacintosh.conf

```
<Directory "file:///Volumes/DBTARA/media/">
   AllowOverride All
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

I attempted to add the following DocumentRoot after the one I already have, but that made my other local servers inaccessible and kept the external one as forbidden.:

```
DocumentRoot "file:///Volumes/DBTARA/media"
<Directory "file:///Volumes/DBTARA/media">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thanks again in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Try taking the `file://` out of the directories, and start with just `/Volumes`. An easy way to make sure you have the correct directory is do `ls /Volumes/DBTARA/media` from the Terminal.

Comment: You are a genius. Doing exactly that worked and I was able to add the document root. Thank you! I definitely owe you for your assistance.